# Как компилировать Vue раздельно для разных страниц?

Tags: vue.js, компиляция, vue-router

У меня есть страницы (карточка объявления, каталог и т.д.) и соответствующие vue шаблоны. И я хочу компилировать Vue шаблоны отдельно, чтобы на выходе получался template1.js, template2.js, а не всё одним файлом.

Comment: используйте динамические импорты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял, то динамический импорт тебе в помощь.
если ты используешь vue-router
в файле router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
routes: [
    {
        path: 'card',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "tempalate1" */ 'путь до компонента1'),
    },
    {
        path: 'catalog',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "tempalate2" */ 'путь до компонента2'),
    }
});
export default router;
```

в файле main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router';

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

если же ты не используешь vue-router, то я тебе советую использовать vue-router.
Подробно можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)